# Should all the labels for yolo be consecutive numbers?

Tags: python, image-processing, object-detection, yolo

I'm working on Yolov8 model with Pascal dataset and the data.Yaml file is like:

```
    train: ../train/images
    val: ../valid/images

nc: 22
names: ['aeroplane', 'bicycle', 'bird', 'boat', 'bottle', 'bus', 'car', 'cat', 'chair', 
'cow', 'diningtable', 'dog', 'horse', 'motorbike', 'person', 'pottedplant', 'sheep', 
 'sofa', 'train', 'tvmonitor','obj1','obj2']
```

From 'aeroplane' to 'tvmonitor' they all have consecutive numbers in label files but obj1 and obj2 are 100 and 101 as their labels.
Can it be a problematic? because I trained the model but I can't see the last two objects in the results.

Comment: Yes, it's problematic for the reason you identified. There's not much we can suggest other than to patch your inputs to comply with yolo's expected format

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll change the labels for the last two objects to be all consecutive numbers.